# Chart line morris.js format date in X axis

Tags: jquery, morris.js

I'm using `morris.js` line chart in order to display different series values.

[image]

I would like to format my X axis so instead of the year I can place a 3 chacarter day of week.

Example:

- 2016-05-10 should be THU-05-10

This is my actual code:

```
Morris.Line({
    element: 'linechart',
    data: data,
    lineColors: ['#819C79', '#fc8710', '#FF6541', '#A4ADD3', '#766B56'],
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['park1','park2','park3','park4','park5'],
    labels: ['PARK 1', ''PARK 2', ''PARK 3', ''PARK 4', ''PARK 5'],
    xLabels: 'day',
    xLabelAngle: 45,
    resize: true
});
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `xLabelFormat` to convert the date to the desired format. Try the `xLabelFormat` function in the following code snippet:

```js
Morris.Line({
  element: 'chart',
  data: [
    { period: '2016-05-10', park1: 200, park2: 200, park3: 50, park4: 10, park5: 0 },
    { period: '2016-05-11', park1: 15, park2: 275, park3: 5, park4: 60, park5: 0 },
    { period: '2016-05-12', park1: 80, park2: 20, park3: 30, park4: 30, park5: 0 },
    { period: '2016-05-13', park1: 100, park2: 200, park3: 250, park4: 50, park5: 0 },
    { period: '2016-05-14', park1: 50, park2: 60, park3: 20, park4: 10, park5: 0 },
    { period: '2016-05-15', park1: 75, park2: 65, park3: 10, park4: 60, park5: 0 },
    { period: '2016-05-16', park1: 175, park2:95, park3: 110, park4: 30, park5: 0 },
    { period: '2016-05-17', park1: 150, park2:95, park3: 90, park4: 111, park5: 0 },
    { period: '2016-05-18', park1: 120, park2:95, park3: 60, park4: 47, park5: 0 },
    { period: '2016-05-19', park1: 60, park2:95, park3: 50, park4: 231, park5: 0 },
    { period: '2016-05-20', park1: 10, park2:95, park3: 100, park4: 80, park5: 0 }
  ],
  lineColors: ['#819C79', '#fc8710', '#FF6541', '#A4ADD3', '#766B56'],
  xkey: 'period',
  ykeys: ['park1','park2','park3','park4','park5'],
  labels: ['PARK 1', 'PARK 2', 'PARK 3', 'PARK 4', 'PARK 5'],
  xLabels: 'day',
  xLabelAngle: 45,
  xLabelFormat: function (d) {
    var weekdays = new Array(7);
    weekdays[0] = "SUN";
    weekdays[1] = "MON";
    weekdays[2] = "TUE";
    weekdays[3] = "WED";
    weekdays[4] = "THU";
    weekdays[5] = "FRI";
    weekdays[6] = "SAT";

    return weekdays[d.getDay()] + '-' + 
           ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + 
           ("0" + (d.getDate())).slice(-2);
  },
  resize: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="chart"></div>
```